# .Dedupe email address with a unique string of numbers in the address

Tags: sql, duplicates

```
SELECT WEB_LOGIN
FROM dbo.Name_Security
WHERE WEB_LOGIN like 'GUEST%[A-Z][A-Z]%@[A-Z][A-Z]%.%[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]%'
```

Trying to run a query to find duplicate email addresses that start with GUEST.
    Then remove the duplicates down to one unique email address.
Issue is they have different numbers referenced in between the GUEST and the actual email address I am trying to de-dupe.

```
EXAMPLE

GUEST635547889019125156DOGU@HTVA.NET
GUEST635547889110697422DOGU@HTVA.NET
GUEST635547889125638828DOGU@HTVA.NET
GUEST635547893650472813DOGU@HTVA.NET
GUEST635547893772132969DOGU@HTVA.NET
GUEST635547964640101719PHILIPKING@GMAIL.COM
GUEST635547965258978672PHILIPKING@GMAIL.COM
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to achieve it with SQL only.

Instead, you can get addresses and process them locally to get a list of the duplicates, like this:

```
// Depending on your context, use any way to get the result of the simple query
// "SELECT WEB_LOGIN FROM dbo.Name_Security"
// as an array of (WEB_LOGIN) in $raw_addresses

// Extract bare-addresses from raw-addresses
$bare_addresses = preg_replace('/^GUEST[\d]+(.*)$/i', '$1', $raw_addresses);
// Then create collections of raw-addresses for each bare-address
foreach ($bare_addresses as $index => $bare_address) {
  $collections[$bare_address][] = $raw_addresses[$index];
}
// Select only collections having more than one index
$duplicates = array_filter($collections, function($indexes) {
  return count($indexes > 1);
});
// Finally use duplicates to whatever you want...
```

You can see it working, based on your given example: [4fi9-dx5v](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/4fi9-dx5v) (click on "Run-F9" to execute).

Answer (score 0):

Consider running nested `REPLACE()` to remove the numbers in the field:

```
SELECT 
    Replace(
        Replace(
            Replace(
                Replace(
                    Replace(
                        Replace(
                            Replace(
                                Replace(
                                    Replace(
                                        Replace(WEB_LOGIN, '0', ''), 
                                        '1', ''), 
                                    '2', ''),
                                '3', ''),
                            '4', ''),
                        '5', ''),
                    '6', ''),
                '7', ''),
            '8', ''),
        '9', '')
FROM dbo.Name_Security
WHERE WEB_LOGIN LIKE 'GUEST%';
```

Alternatively, since you post the `dbo` prefix so assuming this is SQL Server, use a series of string functions --`SUBSTRING()`, `PATINDEX`, `LEN()`, `REVERSE()`-- to parse out the numbers:

```
SELECT  
      SUBSTRING(WEB_LOGIN, 
                LEN(WEB_LOGIN)+1 - PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', REVERSE(WEB_LOGIN))+1, 
                LEN(WEB_LOGIN))
FROM dbo.Name_Security
WHERE WEB_LOGIN LIKE 'GUEST%';
```

One caveat of both options is email addresses that contain numbers but all duplicates will be handled together. Add a `GROUP BY ... HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` to identify such duplicates.